# Opposite of JS onunload()

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i would like to display a simple alert using JavaScript whenever user is viewing mypage (i.e. after switching tabs, or changing windows; between application).

So for example a user has 3 tabs namely google.com, stackoverflow.com and mysite.com. When ever a user switching from google.com to mysite.com i would like to have a simple alert.

Which basically the opposite of onUnload.

I tried using

onLoad, but this does not work as i intended to be.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers,

Comment: An alert every time your page gains focus? I can tell you on my system, it would gain focus precisely *once* before being closed and never opened again.

Comment: Might as well blacklist the domain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page visibility API for this. Check out this excellent jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/cAG5N/

You need some boilerplate from the fiddle to make it work across different browsers, but this is the core of it:

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (!document.hidden) {
        alert('the dialog');
    } 
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I can't promote your answer at the moment. Still within 2 mins grace period.

Answer (score 0):

You just add this to the script:

```
window.onfocus = function () { alert('stuff'); };
```

You should mostdefinitly NOT do that.
It will block the user from doing ANYTHING as the alert will blur the page and result in your page being blocked completely. Even if you prevent that from happening, an alert is blocking and highly annoying in any case.

Comment: @Johnathan, thanks for the tips. Actually i won't alerting the user whenever the page gain focus. Instead i would do a flashtitle when the page is lose focus and reset the page title back to original once its gain focus again.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is a flashtitle?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added  onfocus handler to the body and its working great.

```
<body onfocus="javascript: alert('Hi');">
```